# Lock/Unlock certain sections in the Word document using OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, .net-6.0, openxml

I have a Word document that has the following structure:

Paragraph Header1

Content Paragraph1

Paragraph Header2

Content Paragraph2

Paragraph Header3

Content Paragraph3

I need to find a way how to programmatically lock/unlock certain paragraphs for edit.  I am trying to use the OpenXML library for it.

This link describes how to do in in MS Word.
https://www.guidingtech.com/how-to-lock-parts-of-a-microsoft-word-document/

My code looks like that:

```
for each (Paragraph paragraph in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>())
    {
        if (paragraph.InnerText.Contains("Paragraph Header1"))
        {
           
            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties = paragraph.GetFirstChild<ParagraphProperties>();
            if (paragraphProperties == null)
            {
                paragraphProperties = new ParagraphProperties();
                paragraph.PrependChild(paragraphProperties);
            }

            DocumentProtection documentProtection = new DocumentProtection() { Edit = DocumentProtectionValues.ReadOnly};
            paragraphProperties.Append(documentProtection);
        }
         
        doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

    }
```

Expected result: the code locks only one paragraph.
Actual result: the code works but locks the whole document.

If there is another library besides OpenXML that will do that it is also fine. But I am looking for a free library.